# export the pipeline to a csv file

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, powershell-3.0, powershell-1.0

I am trying to figure out how to export to a csv file.  I have no problem exporting it to excel, yet when I try to export it to a csv file I screw it up.  I left out the ad pull.

```
     Foreach($result in $results){
$User = $result.GetDirectoryEntry()
$DistinguishedName = $USER.DistinguishedName -replace "'", "''"
$CN  = $USER.CN -replace "'", "''"
$name  = $USER.name -replace "'", "''"
$userAccountControl = $USER.userAccountControl
$extensionAttribute7 = $User.extensionattribute7 -replace "'", "''"
$extensionAttribute1 = $User.extensionattribute1 -replace "'", "''"
$operatingSystem = $USER.operatingSystem -replace "'", "''"
$pwdLastSet = [datetime]::FromFileTimeUtc((ConvertADSLargeInteger $USER.pwdLastSet[0]))
 if( ( [datetime]"1900-01-01" - $pwdLastSet ).Days -gt 0 )
{
 $pwdLastSet = [datetime]"1900-01-01"
}
```

## Populate General Sheet(1) with information

```
foreach ($objItem in $result){

    $Sheet1.Cells.Item($intRow, 1) = $CN
    $Sheet1.Cells.Item($intRow, 2) = $operatingSystem
    $Sheet1.Cells.Item($intRow, 3) = $pwdLastSet
    $Sheet1.Cells.Item($intRow, 4) = $DistinguishedName
    $Sheet1.Cells.Item($intRow, 5) = $extensionAttribute7
    $Sheet1.Cells.Item($intRow, 6) = $extensionAttribute1
    }
```

Comment: A ForEach($a in $b) loop does not have a pipeline, so that may be why you can't pipe to CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make an array, fill it with objects based on what you have in your script, then you can loop through that to fill out the spreadsheet, and can also use it to export to CSV.

```
$Users = @()

Foreach($result in $results){
    $User = $result.GetDirectoryEntry()
    $pwdLastSet = [datetime]::FromFileTimeUtc((ConvertADSLargeInteger $USER.pwdLastSet[0]))
    if( ( [datetime]"1900-01-01" - $pwdLastSet ).Days -gt 0 )
    {
        $pwdLastSet = [datetime]"1900-01-01"
    }
    $Users+=[PSCustomObject][Ordered]@{
        User = $User
        DistinguishedName = $USER.DistinguishedName -replace "'", "''"
        CN  = $USER.CN -replace "'", "''"
        name  = $USER.name -replace "'", "''"
        userAccountControl = $USER.userAccountControl
        extensionAttribute7 = $User.extensionattribute7 -replace "'", "''"
        extensionAttribute1 = $User.extensionattribute1 -replace "'", "''"
        operatingSystem = $USER.operatingSystem -replace "'", "''"
        pwdLastSet = $pwdLastSet
        }
}

For($intRow=1;$intRow -le $Users.count;$intRow++){
    $Sheet1.Cells.Item($intRow, 1) = $Users[$intRow-1].CN
    $Sheet1.Cells.Item($intRow, 2) = $Users[$intRow-1].operatingSystem
    $Sheet1.Cells.Item($intRow, 3) = $Users[$intRow-1].pwdLastSet
    $Sheet1.Cells.Item($intRow, 4) = $Users[$intRow-1].DistinguishedName
    $Sheet1.Cells.Item($intRow, 5) = $Users[$intRow-1].extensionAttribute7
    $Sheet1.Cells.Item($intRow, 6) = $Users[$intRow-1].extensionAttribute1
}

$Users | Export-Csv C:\Path\To\NewFile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply pipe `$result` into a `ForEach-Object` loop and select the relevant properties from the object and export:

```
$results | % { $_.GetDirectoryEntry() } |
  select CN, operatingSystem, pwdLastSet, DistinguishedName,
         extensionattribute7, extensionattribute1 |
  Export-Csv 'C:\output.csv' -NoType
```

You can use calculated properties to replace properties with modified versions of themselves:

```
$results | % { $_.GetDirectoryEntry() } |
  select @{n='CN';e={$_.CN -replace "'","''"}},
         @{n='operatingSystem';e={$_.operatingSystem -replace "'","''"}},
         @{n='pwdLastSet';e={
           $d = [DateTime]::FromFileTimeUtc($_.pwdLastSet[0])
           if ( $d.Date -lt [DateTime]"1900-01-01" ) {
             [DateTime]"1900-01-01"
           } else {
             $d
           }
         }},
         @{n='DistinguishedName';e={$_.DistinguishedName -replace "'","''"}},
         @{n='extensionattribute7';e={$_.extensionattribute7 -replace "'","''"}},
         @{n='extensionattribute1';e={$_.extensionattribute1 -replace "'","''"}} |
  Export-Csv 'C:\output.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: That's an elegant solution

Comment: You are a genius Ansgar.  I will have to learn about hash tables!